# Finding what is most commonly purchased with a specific product - PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, associations

I am trying to find the most common products purchased with the product 'SWE' but am currently stuck. I have the variables 'product' and 'sales_invoice'

So far I have this code:

```
df_pairs = df_pairs = df.groupby(df['product'].str.contains('SWE'))['sales_invoice']
print(df_pairs.head())
```

it results in a list of sales invoices containing SWE but does not list the remaining info of the sales invoice(specifically the other products listed on that sales invoice which is what I'm looking for)

Any ideas?

EDIT: it's not printing all of the columns values - e.g. I want it to have sales invoice '22' for example which shows 'SWE' as specified, along with the other products it has on that invoice which are 'EGG' and 'BIS'

example of df:

[image]

Comment: Could you specify more on the output you want? Do you mean it isn't printing out all of the instances/rows or all of the columns?

Comment: @Hanna sorry, it's not printing all of the columns values - e.g. I want it to have sales invoice '22' for example which shows 'SWE' as specified, along with the other products it has on that invoice which are 'EGG' and 'BIS' - does this clarify things for you? :)

Comment: @Poppy,  After the group by operation, you cannot see all the details one by one. One way is to show the members of the group in the form of a list. Could you also add us an example of **df** and what is  your expected output ? to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since there may be more than one product in an order, we create a line for each product, then we group them according to sales_invoice and assign the products in each order to a list, then we show the distribution of each list as a dictionary. In addition, you can filter by SWE or see the product distribution regardless of the order (last example)

example data:

```
    Date        sales_invoice   product quantity    product_amount
0   02-01-2016  1               SWE     1           3.13
1   02-01-2016  2               SWE     1           3.13
2   02-01-2016  2               EGG     2           5.46
3   02-01-2016  2               EGG     1           5.46
4   02-01-2016  2               EGG     1           5.46
5   02-01-2016  3               0H2     1           5.58
```

```
#when quantity > 1, if product_amount=quantity * product_price use this.
#import numpy as np
#df['product_amount']=np.where(df['quantity'] > 1,df['product_amount'] / df['quantity'],df['product_amount'])

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['quantity'])].drop(['quantity'],axis=1) #append a new row for every product
df_pairs= df.groupby('sales_invoice').agg({'sales_invoice':'count','product':list,'product_Amount':'sum'})

def get_dists(x):
    counts = dict()
    for i in x:
      counts[i] = counts.get(i, 0) + 1
      
    return dict(sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True))
      
df_pairs['product_distribution']=df_pairs['product'].apply(lambda x: get_dists(x))
df_pairs=df_pairs.rename(columns={'sales_invoice':'product_count','product_Amount':'total_amount'})
print(df_pairs)
'''
sales_invoice   product_count   product                          total_amount product_distribution
1               1               ['SWE']                              3.13     {'SWE': 1}
2               5               ['SWE', 'EGG', 'EGG', 'EGG', 'EGG']  24.97    {'EGG': 4, 'SWE': 1}
3               1               ['0H2']                              5.58     {'0H2': 1}

'''
```

now, if you want to get only values that contain "SWE":

```
mask = df_pairs['product'].apply(lambda x: 'SWE' in x)
df_filtered = df_pairs[mask]
```

or if you need only distributions and get top n products:

```
df_filtered=pd.json_normalize(df_filtered['product_distribution']).T.fillna(0)
df_filtered['total']=df_filtered[0] + df_filtered[1]
df_filtered=df_filtered.sort_values(by='total',ascending=False)
#The total column will give you what you want.
```

Comment: awesome thanks! & is there a way to sort it so I can see the top 5 products that are frequently bought with SWE?

Comment: I added it to the end of the answer, can you check?

Comment: yep perfect thank you, I was doing by=count and it wasn't working but this makes more sense - legend!!